# problem in understanding JQuery selectors

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

for example if I click on the add+ 9 times, I'll have 10 boxes. but after that, Only if A click the last box, it will hide. (I want hiding the specific box by clicking on that box). by the way after click (and desappering) the last box, the other boxe wont hide in any way
whats my problem?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add").click(function(){
        $(".test:last").clone().insertAfter(this);
    })
    $(".test").click(function(){
        $(this).hide("slow");
    })
})

<div id="add">ADD+</div>
<div class="test" style="border:1px solid black; width:70px; height:25px;">
    box
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're only hooking up the one that exists when the document loads. Change

```
$(".test").click(function(){
    $(this).hide("slow");
})
```

to

```
$(".test").live('click', function(){
    $(this).hide("slow");
});
```

`click` is for hooking up events to elements that *already exist*. Using `live`, you can be more speculative and say "hook up this event for any that already exist, **and** any I add later that match this selector." There's also `delegate` which can be useful if you want the functionality of `live`, but one for descendants of a particular element.

Details:

- [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/)
- [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
- [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Answer (score 3):

Use `.clone(true)` instead of just `.clone()` to copy the event handlers as well.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/hQ5Qc/

---

I'd also add that you may want to change the selector from this:

```
$(".test:last")
```

to this:

```
$(".test:visible:last")
```

so if you hide the last box, you're not cloning one that was already hidden.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/hQ5Qc/2/

Comment: That's another way to go, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".test").click(function(){
         $(this).hide("slow");
    })

    $("#add").click(function(){
         $(".test:visible:last").clone(true).insertAfter(this);
    })
})
```

added `:visible` per comment suggestion

Comment: not different, sometimes you will get many answers to easy question that are all the same in functionality